# How do I fix the ngspice warning "Can't open viewport for graphics."?

Tags: linux, ngspice

I'm trying to see some waveform plots for SPICE circuits with `ngspice`. As far as I can tell, the `plot` command is supposed to raise a window with a nice chart in it. But I keep getting this error message:

```
ERROR: (internal)  This operation is not defined for display type printf.
Can't open viewport for graphics.
```

I'm on linux mint 17.3 (ubuntu 10.04 lucid?).

I've tried:

- Installing `libxaw-dev` as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/461466/cant-open-viewport-for-graphics-in-ng-spice/575866#575866
- Compiling from source as per https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/bugs/263/#27fb
- compiling with `--enable-xgraph`
- `xhost +`, just in case

But I'm still seeing this error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEBACK - I was running my script in batch mode, thinking that stuff in `.control` would run automatically, pop up a waveform window and exit.

Batch mode does not do this.

Instead, just `ngspice circuit.cir`.